# Invalid covariant return type on inherited unary operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I'm using a base class to define an interface for any object with certain available operations. When I actually implement a derived class, I get "invalid covariant return type" errors on all my unary operators (but not my binary operators). Here is the relevant code:

```
class elem {
    public:
    virtual elem operator+(const elem &other) const = delete;
    virtual elem operator-() const = delete;
    virtual elem operator*(const elem &other) const = delete;
};

class specialElem : public elem {
    public:
    virtual specialElem operator+(const specialElem &other) const {
        //...
    }
    virtual specialElem operator-() const {
        //...
    }
    virtual specialElem operator*(const specialElem &other) const {
        //...
    }
};
```

I looked up this error message, and the answer was "using the derived class as return types (instead of the base class) only works when you return by reference/pointer, not by value". But now I don't understand; if this is true, why do the binary operators work but not the unary ones?

Bonus: what is the "normal C++ way" of implementing an interface when we want to return by value?

Comment: Covariant return type must be a pointer or a reference; you are returning by value. Your binary operands do not override those in the base class, but instead overload them - they take parameters of a different type; that's why they can have a different return type.

Comment: Ohhh, good catch! That's very subtle indeed.

Comment: The normal C++ way is you don't: it makes no sense to return a polymorphic object by value. That way lies [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You completely answered my question, thanks!